# Force empty repeated section

Tags: orbeon

I have created a repeated section and by default when form loads first time it shows the section with the first row empty and then it lets to erase this row.

Is there any way to force the section to be completely empty the first time?

I am using Orbeon Forms 2017.1.1.201709122316 PE. This is the code:

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
         xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
         xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
         xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
         xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
         xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
         xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
         xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
         xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
    <xh:head>
        <xh:title/>
        <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

            <!-- Main instance -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
                <form>
                    <rep-section-1>
                        <rep-section-1-iteration>
                            <control-1/>
                        </rep-section-1-iteration>

                    </rep-section-1>
                </form>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Bindings -->
            <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
                <xf:bind id="rep-section-1-bind" name="rep-section-1" ref="rep-section-1">
                    <xf:bind id="rep-section-1-iteration-bind" ref="rep-section-1-iteration"
                             name="rep-section-1-iteration">
                        <xf:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" ref="control-1"/>
                    </xf:bind>

                </xf:bind>
            </xf:bind>

            <!-- Metadata -->
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <metadata>
                    <application-name>test</application-name>
                    <form-name>repeated</form-name>
                    <title xml:lang="en"/>
                    <description xml:lang="en"/>
                </metadata>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- Attachments -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <attachments>
                    <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                    <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
                </attachments>
            </xf:instance>

            <!-- All form resources -->
            <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
            <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <resources>
                    <resource xml:lang="en">
                        <rep-section-1>
                            <label>Repeated Section</label>
                        </rep-section-1>
                        <control-1>
                            <label>Field1</label>
                            <hint/>
                            <alert/>
                        </control-1>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </xf:instance>
            <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="rep-section-1-template"
                         xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                <rep-section-1-iteration>
                    <control-1/>
                </rep-section-1-iteration>
            </xf:instance>

            </xf:model>
    </xh:head>
    <xh:body>
        <fr:view>
            <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
                <fr:section id="rep-section-1-control" bind="rep-section-1-bind" repeat="content"
                            template="instance('rep-section-1-template')"
                            apply-defaults="true"
                            fb:initial-iterations="first"
                            collapsible="true">
                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/rep-section-1/label"/>
                    <fr:grid>
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:input>
                            </xh:td>
                            <xh:td/>
                        </xh:tr>
                    </fr:grid>
                </fr:section>
            </fr:body>
        </fr:view>
    </xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

Next images explain what I comment:

1. Default repeated section after first loading
   [image: Default repeated section]
2. Desired repeated section after first loading
   [image: Desired repeated section]

Comment: I am not sure to understand the situation. Shouldn't the first iteration of your repeated section should be empty when you load the `/new` page for that form, unless you set some default values for some fields? Could you maybe provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: @avernet I have edited this question and attached images to trying to explain the behaviour

Comment: Got it, I think I understand, and have posted an answer below to your question. And if course, feel free to let me know in the comments if I somehow misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure this in the Section Settings dialog, clicking on the "No minimum" radio button, which is highlighted in the screenshot below and remove the first iteration in Form Builder

I am not sure what the status of this is in 2017.1.1 (the version you mentioned you were using), but note that there was an issue in 2018.2.2 that prevented a new section iteration being created after the last section iteration had been removed. This is fixed, and will be included in 2018.2.3 release. For information on that issue, see [#4018](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4018).

[image: "No minimum" radio in the Section Settings dialog]

Comment: Hi, @avernet thanks but that is exactly the configuration that I have, except "Freeze Repetitions" section that it looks that it is not included in this version. I will try to do some kind of workaround because my limitation is that we are using the Orbeon version included in other platform belonging to SAP and the integration has been done by them. I don't know if it will possible to upgrade Orbeon without upgrade the product.

Comment: @HCP Indeed, the version of Orbeon Forms shipped by SAP might not be the latest one, but they are in my experience pretty good at upgrading Orbeon Forms before they make a release of their product. This being said, it looks to me like you'd like to have no iteration show when the form is loaded. For that, you don't need the "Freeze Repetitions"; you just need to set the minimum to "no minimum", and remove the first iteration in Form Builder. Does that make sense, or am I misunderstanding what you're aiming for?

Comment: For more on what freezing certain repetition, see the [Freeze repetitions](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/form-editor/repeated-grids#freeze-repetitions) section of the documentation.

Comment: you were right with "you just need to set the minimum to "no minimum", and remove the first iteration in Form Builder" i had to remove the first iteration form Form Builder, now is the time in wich i feel really stupid. Thanks! I will edit your response and add this part.

Comment: @HCP Excellent, I'm glad that worked, and thank you for the update.